# Synchronized access to UITableViewDelegate logic

Tags: iphone, ios, synchronized, didselectrowatindexpath, uitableview

I'd like to ask a question about table view and `@synchronized` contruct.
I have to execute the code inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` once, even if user keep tapping on table cell...

I have a table used as menu in a game. I'd like to provide synchronized access to the logic implemented in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

I worte the following code:

```
//condition = YES in init code

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        @synchronized( self)
        {
            if( !condition)
            {
                NSLog(@"multiple execution is not allowed...");
                return;
            }
            condition = NO;
            ...
            //code
            ...
        }
    }
```

I tested it on my ipone 3gs with ios 4.3.4 and worked (i made tests and the behaviour is as expected) but my client tested it on his 3g with ios 3.x installed and it seems not to work.

I thought at using GCD (by enclosing code in `dispatch_once()`), but it's supported starting from ios 4.x.

Have you any insight on why  `@synchronized` doesn't work on my client's phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@synchronized` should not be not needed here.

- you can expect the delegate call to be made from the main thread (assuming you do not call it).
- `dispatch_once` seems like an unusual choice here. if you are sure it is good, try `pthread_once` for iOS 3. it's odd because it operates using mutable global state. IOW, "I only ever want to make one table".
- testing a BOOL is fast.

My guess? Your table is being removed (view unloading) and may fail to be recreated on reload.

Comment: Thanks foryour answer. I thought of using dispatch_once to find a way to execute code associated with the tapping of a table row once. I verified the problem by setting up a breakpoint inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath implementation and while stopped at the breakpoint, i tapped another time and another thread entered into didSelectRowAtIndexPath, so i find myself with a race condition..

Comment: hmmm... not sure what to say if you are sure you call it only from the main thread. have you by chance *disabled* objc or c++ exceptions? if so, try it with them enabled. normally, I'd just pull the logic out to a separate method. otherwise, there may be other portions of the program which are not thread safe or you may be initializing and destroying in an unconventional manner.